# Ruby: Each time an image is clicked, how to play a different audio clip?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, audio

I am working on a project in Ruby and each time an image is clicked (there will be multiple images on the page), I want an audio clip specific to that image played. Based on what I have so far, only the first audio clip will play each time any image is clicked. Please see my code below:

```js
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/red-horse-dot-m_2778460a.jpg" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
  <audio id="audio" src="audios/track1.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/3/O/G/7/D/green-circle-hi.png" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
  <audio id="audio" src="audios/track2.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:ruby]? From what I can see, your code is entirely [tag:ecmascript] and [tag:html].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
  function play(emt){
    var audio = emt.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    audio.play();
  }
</script>

<div onclick="play(this)">
  <img src="https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/red-horse-dot-m_2778460a.jpg" value="PLAY">
  <audio src="audios/track1.mp3" ></audio>
</div>

<div onclick="play(this)">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/3/O/G/7/D/green-circle-hi.png" value="PLAY">
  <audio src="audios/track2.mp3" ></audio>
</div>
```

I changed your code so that when `onclick` calls `play`, it passes the `<div>` which was clicked as a parameter. Then `play` looks for the audio element attached to the image.

As a rule of thumb, you should never have two elements with the same id on the same page.

Comment: I don't think this will work @eiko.  Image tags can't contain elements as far as I know.  HTML allows `<img>` without closing brackets whereas XHTML would force you to use `<img/>` but that doesn't mean the element below it is nested inside.

Comment: @DeezCashews you're absolutely right, thanks! i modified my code (and tested it this time) so that it will run properly. same idea, but i moved the onclick to the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getElementById` query is returning more than one element since both ids are 'audio'.  Give them unique ids and pass what you want played into the function like so:

```
<script>
  function play(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    audio.play();
  }
</script>

<div>
  <img src="https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/red-horse-dot-m_2778460a.jpg" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('audio1')">
      <audio id="audio1" src="audios/track1.mp3" ></audio>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/O/3/O/G/7/D/green-circle-hi.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('audio2')">
  <audio id="audio2" src="audios/track2.mp3" ></audio>
</div>
```